# Plotting a heatmap co-occurrence matrix of words from documents

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, heatmap

This code generates the co-occurrence of any words I want from the documents. It works great. But I want to plot the result as a heatmap. Is it possible ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
a=((open('A.txt').read()).lower()).split()
c=((open('C.txt').read()).lower()).split()
f=((open('F.txt').read()).lower()).split()
documents=[a,f,c]
import math
names=[...] #important words
for a in names:
     for b in names:
          count = 0
          for x in documents:
          if a != b:
                if a in x and b in x:
                     count += 1

          else:
                n = x.count(a)
                if n >= 2:
                      count += math.factorial(n)/math.factorial(n - 2)/2

    print('{} x {} = {}'.format(a, b, count))
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Type `help(plt.imshow)` for details of plotting.

Comment: Hello, thank you for anwseing. How can I do that ? I just need to know which variables I need to define  ?

Comment: You need to define square array of word colocation and fill it instead of printing. Also please note that the `print()` in your code shall be iterated in the seconf `for` loop

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your help.